# What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that there are $m$ nonisomorphic groups of order $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, groups-enumeration

This following  question given in Gallian's algebra text:

What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that there are two nonisomorphic groups of order $n$?

The answer for this question given in text book is $n=4$ as $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ served our purpose.I did this by inspection.

Now i wanted to generalise this question i.e; i wanted to know **What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that there are EXACTLY $m$ nonisomorphic groups of order $n$?**

Here inspection does'nt work.So please guide me to get to the result.

Thank you!

Comment: For general $m$, this is an open problem.

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear. Do you mean exactly $m$ groups or at least $m$ groups of order $n$. In any case, this question is far too difficult!" See for example https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf

Comment: Fun fact that I hadn't realized, OEIS A000001 is the [number of groups of order $n$](https://oeis.org/A000001).

Comment: If exactly $m$ was intended, then this function is called ${\rm moa}(n)$ in the referenced paper, although I believe it is still unknown whether there is exists such an $n$ for all $m$. The problem of whether there is an $n$ with ${\rm gnu}(n) = n$ is also open.

Comment: I like what amounts to be an answer about and to the question above, @DerekHolt I'd love for you to compile them and post an answer.

Comment: There have been lots of previous discussions of this topic - for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630931/

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows.  This is an open problem, at this level of generality.  In fact, even the weaker question of whether, given a positive integer $m$, there is an $n$ such that the number of groups of order $n$ is equal to $m$ remains open, as far as I know.

There is a very readable [survey](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf) on the subject that you might enjoy.

Comment: Nice answer, @Derek!